# Neovim / Vim UTF-8 characters not working

Tags: text, encoding, text-editor, neovim

I'm new to nvim and vim in general. been using for about a month. I wasn't really bother about characters only really needed latin-1. However, I've been installing a lot more plugins to customize my env, and for note-taking and assignments. I've noticed that some of my characters aren't displaying correctly. can anyone pls help? this can be ez fix but nothing works. [image: my nvim rc]
[image: example of env]

I'll post a screenshot to address the missing characters, I keep getting the replacement char "?"

any help is appreciated.

changed config file, changed bashrc file, and .vimrc. nothing works :(

Comment: Do your terminal is setup to support UTF-8 characters? e.g. if you `cat` a file which contain UTF-8 characters? vi are just programs which use terminal capabilities.

Comment: Which character(s) render as replacement char � ? Please [edit] your question to share some of them… Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: Do a `cat random.org` and check if terminal can display it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for the help. You made me realize this was a terminal issue, and not a software issue(neovim). I ended up finding out that the default font (Consolas) was the issue. I switched to a nerdfont, and all character types are working. I found this @ https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/306  if interested. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

thanks Giacomo Catenazzi. I thought it was the actual piece of software (neovim), and not the terminal that was causing this encoding issue. This could be because I am using WSL2. I should've stated this in the original prompt.

Eventually, this made me realize that the characters are likely not available in the default font (Consolas).

Just never thought the problem was the default font, it seems like an issue that would never be an issue to begin with. Maybe WSL?

P.S. I used nerdfonts for my terminal. If anyone has an issue, just change font in terminal properties.

Thank you!

Comment: It may be a terminal bug. For *normal* text, modern display system (built in in the operating system or in the usual output libraries) will use character on other fonts if the selected font doesn't have such character) [Note: as last fallback: e.g. non-ligature should have priority]. But terminals are special (also on font handling), so just *may* be a bug. There may be reasons.